Question and answer review queues
This is an extension of the question I asked on Differences in number of question reviews whereby I have now seen the queue rise to 11 pending reviews of questions and answers.
As this is a peer community reviewed group, which relies on the peer community for moderation and effectiveness of the site, I have spent the time reviewing as well as asking and answering questions.  It doesn't take long, yet it seems from @AliceD's answer that there may be some who are not reviewing when they could be benefiting themselves and others by doing so.  Reading AliceD's answer again, he says...

After some time, review items eventually disappear, meaning that poor-quality questions and answers remain open while they should've been closed.

With this in mind, there can be questions or answers which can be damaging for those asking and as CogSciSE is

a question and answer site for researchers, academics, students, and enthusiasts needing expert answers to advanced questions in the "cognitive sciences"

having poor answers can also be damaging for the reputation of the professions represented. 
How can we encourage more people to review votes for question re-opening and closure?

Nice post and very relevant. Thanks for this.

At the risk of repeating myself, I still believe the greatest contribution that can be made to encourage people to keep the review-queue at a manageable size is to add a new close-vote reason. This, along with the other changes proposed in the "Call to Action" would make it easier to close and re-open questions.

Indeed, often I really have to think which of the close vote reasons is justified when "lack of context /research" would be the actual reason
